# Using WiX to target specific folder

Tags: wix, installation

I'm using Wix to create an installer that will search for a directory on the user's PC and install a related application to that directory.  For example, I need to install to the folder `ProductA\Utilities`, the location of which is outside of my control.

To accomplish this, I have tried the following:

```
<Property Id="UTILITIES_DIR">
    <DirectorySearch Id="FindUtilsDir" Path="ProductA\Utilities"/>
</Property>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <!-- WiX requires me to use a special folder at some point -->
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="ProgramFiles"> 
        <Directory Id="UTILITIES_DIR">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyUtility"/>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

This all works well when I'm running the installer by double clicking, however, when I run the installer through msiexec.exe, the `UTILITIES_DIR` is found, but overwritten immediately after:

From log file:

```
MSI (c) (C0:0C) [16:49:34:064]: 
    PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETDIR property. Its value is 'F:\'.
MSI (c) (C0:0C) [16:49:34:064]: 
    PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ProgramFilesFolder property. 
    Its current value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\'. Its new value: 'F:\ProgramFiles\'.
MSI (c) (C0:0C) [16:49:34:064]: 
    PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying UTILITIES_DIR property. 
    Its current value is 'C:\ProductA\Utilities'. Its new value: 'F:\ProgramFiles\'.
```

It's worth noting that F:\ on my machine is a network share to parts of C:\ and it reports the exact same free space as C:\, so it seems that I'm getting lucky when running the .msi directly and TARGETDIR is set to C:\, but when running from msiexec, TARGETDIR is getting set to F:.

Is there a way to accomplish finding a specific directory that may be in any root?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the SourceDir to WindowsVolume. So it will not change anymore.

```
<SetDirectory Id="SourceDir " Value="[WindowsVolume]" />
```